# Error when trying to create test project with vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin

I have installed the Vaadin plugin for Eclipse.

I created a test sample project, now I get the following error:

> 'E:/Programming/Java/Eclipse/configuration/com.vaadin.integration.eclipse/download/gwt-dev/2.3.0/gwt-dev.jar' in project 'test' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file

I even went to the above path and copied the file 'gwt-dev.jar' from there into the libraries folder for this web app, however now I am getting this error:

> Archive for required library: 'WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/gwt-dev.jar' in project 'test' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file

How do I resolve this error? FYI, I am following the instructions given in the book "Learning Vaadin" by Nicolas Frankel to create a test project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error seems to suggest that either you don't have the rights to read the file (which I doubt, since you were able to copy it), or the file is damaged. Check that the md5-signature matches with the one given [here](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/google/gwt/gwt-dev/2.3.0/gwt-dev-2.3.0.jar.asc.md5). If it doesn't match, the file has been corrupted, and you need to download it again.

http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/browse/com/google/gwt/gwt-dev/2.3.0/